# Why is having an uncountable Hamel Basis a problem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I was taught my functional analysis class that Hamel basis is uncountable in an infinite dimensional normed linear space is the one of the reasons why we need topology to develop the theory in infinite dimensional spaces. Could someone elaborate on why this is and provide some example comparing to the finite dimensional case?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask that question to the one who said that. It's hard to guess what was on his/her mind. For me topology is always relevant, regardless of dimension. Perhaps he/she was referring to weak topology? But that would be relevant for infinite countable as well. Unless only Banach spaces are of interest? Well, I'm not going to guess. Ask the author.

Comment: Hamel basis is often uncountable - we prefer countable bases.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong: Consider the real vector space ${\mathbb R}$. It is uncountable but has basis consisting of a single element.

Comment: We like to work with finite or countable things. Everything else can get very complex and set theoretical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the correct statements:

1. If $V$ is a vector space over a countable field and $V$ has uncountable cardinality, then (every) Hamel basis of $V$ is uncountable. The proof is straightforward counting.
2. If $V$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, then  (every) Hamel basis of $V$ is uncountable. To prove this, suppose that $V$ has a countable basis $S=\{e_n: n\in {\mathbb N}\}$. Consider subspaces $V_n=span(\{e_1,...,e_n\})\subset V$. Then each $V_n$ has empty interior in $V$ (since it is a proper linear subspace  of $V$). By the Baire theorem, the union $\bigcup_{n\in {\mathbb N}} V_n$ has empty interior in $V$. Thus,  $S$ cannot be a Hamel basis of $V$.
3. Saying that "we need topological vector spaces because Hamel bases of Banach spaces are uncountable" gets things backwards.

In fact, functional analysis (Hilbert and Banach spaces, topological vector spaces) and their **topological bases** was developed in order to address some problems coming from real and complex analysis, differential equations (ordinary and partial) and, later, mathematical physics. In all these applications, vector spaces came with natural topologies (and more) and, frequently, topological bases. For instance, if you think about Taylor's expansion, you are trying to approximate a smooth (actually, analytic) function by finite sums of monomials, with monomials  serving as a topological basis of the vector space you are studying. Or, in the case of Fourier series, you are working with a topological basis (trig functions) of a suitable vector space ($L^2$ or, more generally, $L^p$). When you prove that the Fourier series of a function converges (in a suitable sense) to the function, you are establishing that trig polynomials form a topological basis.

Is the existence of a Hamel basis useful in functional analysis? Not much, as far as I know. In contrast, some other implicit constructions relying upon the Axiom of Choice are useful. For instance, Hahn-Banach theorem,
one of the most basic and useful results of functional analysis is proven via an implicit construction that relies upon the Axiom of Choice. The existence of a Hamel basis is useful if one thinks of vector spaces purely algebraically. But then, this is not functional analysis but algebra.

Comment: (+1) for *"$\ldots$ their topological bases was developed in order to address some problems coming from real and complex analysis $\ldots$"*, which I think is more on target. The OP's comment relies on things quite irrelevant (and not much known) when Volterra, Fréchet, Hilbert, and others were developing various general theories to exploit the geometric analogies that were "in the air" during roughly the 1880's to the 1910's, theories that were more systematized in the 1920's and early 1930's to what we now know as functional analysis.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Right, agreed. I wish such background was explained in the beginning, when people teach functional analysis. I remember, when I was first learning functional analysis, I took in in parallel with a PDE class full of Sobolev spaces. But the two classes could not have been taught more disjointly.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler classical example of a vector space with a not denumerable Hamel basis is the space whose elements are the real numbers $\mathbb R$ and the field of  the scalars is the filed of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$. This space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ is infinite dimensional with a non denumerable basis. This means that any real number can be expressed as a linar combination,  with rational coefficients, of a finite set of elements of this basis, but we can never know a way to represents constructively all those elements. More, since [almost all the real numbers are not computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), also almost all the elements of the basis are non computable. In other words: the elements of the Hamel basis exist, but we cannot explicetly (constructively) express them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't necessarily that it is uncountable rather that such basis sets are shown to exist non-contructively. So, you can't really use them much since you don't know anything about them besides that they are basis sets.
Topologies enable us to decompose vectors in a way very similiar to basis sets however with the added benefit that those decompositions are (more) constructive and therefore provide more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

An answer which is maybe not exactly you are looking for, but I think is relevant, is that uncountable sums of positive numbers always diverge. (This can be found in Rudin I think, or I found this document http://math.bu.edu/people/prakashb/Math/ar.pdf)

So while infinite series make sense, and are useful in understanding infinite dimensional vector spaces, sums which are uncountable aren't meaningful. In particular, you can't have something like Bessel's inequality for an uncountable basis since the infinite sum is never even defined.

Comment: In fact, Bessel's inequality can be proven for uncountable orthonormal systems. Then only countably many of the arising coefficients are non-zero